# How to read chunks of lines in different ways mandated by the preceding, triggering text in Python

Tags: python, macos, loops

Although I'm a total beginner in Python, it's been great fun programming with it. I'm on Python interpreter 2.7.5 on OSX. What I'm trying to do is to read chunks of lines from an HTML file that I've first processed with BeautifulSoup to get the text content out. So, I want to treat these desired chunks of lines differently by the preceding triggering text. However, my code fails at differentiating between the two triggers and treats everything by the "Trigger Type 1". If I can get a solution to this problem, I will add even more different trigger types.

First the HTML stripped temp_file.txt to be read:

```
lots of unnecessary data on these lines
TRIGGER Type 1
lots of unnecessary data on these lines
Name:
String_to_be_found1
unnecessary data line
54301957(the desired number)

lots of unnecessary data on these lines
TRIGGER Type 2
lots of unnecessary data on these lines
Name2:
String_to_be_found2
unnecessary data line
unnecessary data line
unnecessary data line
54139851(the desired number)

lots of unnecessary data on these lines

TRIGGER Type 1
lots of unnecessary data on these lines
Name:
String_to_be_found3
unnecessary data line
425827459(the desired number)
```

And my code:

```
f = open("temp_file.txt", "r+")
f2 = open("my_output_file.txt", 'w')

for line in iter(f.readline, ''):
    if 'TRIGGER' in line:
        if 'Type 1' in line:
            for line in f:
                if 'Name' in line:
                    desired_string = f.next()
                    f.next()
                    desired_number=f.next()
                    f2.write(desired_string + desired_number + '\n')
        if 'Type 2' in line:
                if 'Name2' in line:
                    f.next()
                    desired_string = f.next()
                    f.next()
                    f.next()
                    f.next()
                    desired_number=f.next()
                    f2.write(desired_string + desired_number + '\n')
f.close()
f2.close()
```

I've been banging my head against a wall with this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit wrong, if `Type 1` is the type that is first found, then it would treat all lines after that as `Type 1` as you are again looping over `f` inside it and you are not exiting from that inner loop until the end of file is reached. It would not work like that.

You should look into defining a kind of flag or so, which you change when you find a line with `TRIGGER` in it , according to the type of the trigger.

Also, you can directly iterate over the `file` , it would iterate over each line, you do not need to iterate over `iter(f.readline, '')` .

Example -

```
f = open("temp_file.txt", "r+")
f2 = open("my_output_file.txt", 'w')

flag = None
for line in f:
    if 'TRIGGER' in line:
        if 'Type 1' in line:
            flag = 1
        elif 'Type 2' in line:
            flag = 2
    elif flag == 1:
        <do processing for `Type 1`>
    elif flag == 2:
        <do processing for `Type 2`>
f.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Incredible, I banged my head against a wall for another couple of hours and came up with a solution myself. I think it's quite near to what you taught me. I used booleans. TRIGGER Type 1 got a boolean with either False or True. The same thing for Type 2. Before entering the main loop I checked for the first hit of Trigger and so the loop was entered with either Type1 and Type2 boolean being true. However, your code is more sophisticated, as it uses only one additional variable - the flag. I will use your solution. Many thanks, indeed!

Comment: Yes, it goes without saying that I accept your answer. I just tried your code and could make it work. For some reason I had to add a few break commands and also I had to do the flagging process once again in the end of the main loop, otherwise I got stuck to a same kind of problem as in the original code (the program entered the main loop with one of the flags been selected forever). My final code is seen below. Feel free to comment if I misunderstood/made it clumsier without a reason. Again, many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, I read Kumar's helpful answer (see above) and could make the code work. In my case, I had to make some minor alterations. I'm not sure if they all were 100% needed, but this code worked for me:

```
f = open("temp_file.txt", "r+")
f2 = open("my_output_file.txt", 'w')

flag = None
for line in f:
        if 'TRIGGER' in line:
            if 'Type 1' in line:
                flag = 1
                break
            elif 'Type 2' in line:
                flag = 2
                break
        elif flag == 1:
            for line in f:
                    if 'Name:' in line:
                        print 'Test version of the program: Trigger type 1 detected'
                        break
        elif flag == 2:
            for line in f:
                    if 'Name2:' in line:
                        print 'Test version of the program: Trigger type 2 detected'
                        break
        for line in f:
                if 'TRIGGER' in line:
                    if 'Type 1' in line:
                        flag = 1
                        break
                    elif 'Type 2' in line:
                        flag = 2
                        break
    f.close()
    f2.close()
```